# parentActivityName is a fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm doing a tab activity composed with fragments. In one of my fragments I launch an activity from which I'd like to get back with the arrow on the upper left.

I've tried to declare my fragment as an activity and it works like that but I'm not sure of the viability of such a thing since Android still says " is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity'"

```
<activity android:name=".ParameterFragment"/>
<activity android:name=".parameters.ChangeMailActivity"
          android:parentActivityName=".ParameterFragment">
          <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                     android:value=".ParameterFragment"/>
</activity>
```

Comment: Is `ParameterFragment` an activity ?

Comment: No it's a fragment

Comment: You can't put a Fragment as parent. Instead you have to use the Activity that contains the Fragment.

Comment: Then how to return to the correct tab and not the first tab of my activity?

Comment: You should not need this in the Manifest anyway. If you start a new Activity from your Fragment, the old Activity will be paused. Wenn you finished the new Activity the old Activity should be resumed from the same state i.e. with the correct Fragment loaded.